# Can't add a local direcotry as a depdency (WSL2, Ubuntu-22.04, node)

Tags: node.js, symlink, wsl-2, ubuntu-22.04

This is parts of my package.json

```json
"dependencies": {
        "pkgname": "file:dirname"
}
```

when I run `npm i`, following error occurs:

```
npm ERR! code EISDIR
npm ERR! syscall symlink
npm ERR! path \\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu-22.04\home\jhs\project
npm ERR! dest \\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu-22.04\home\jhs\project\node_modules\pkgname
npm ERR! errno -4068
npm ERR! EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, symlink '\\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu-22.04\home\jhs\project\pkgname' -> '\\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu-22.04\home\jhs\project\node_modules\pkgname'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\victo\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-12-09T16_26_57_168Z-debug.log
```

In Windows, same project is working.

Expecting:
installed `./dirname` as `pkgname` in `node_modules` successfully. it should be a symlink.